# Get notified when list of custom type property is changed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a class and one of the properties is a list of a custom class.

The caller gets the list and is adding instances of class to the list.  How do I get notified that the list has been updated?

```
Private _list as List(of MyType)
Private _totalField1 as Integer

Public Property MyTypeList As List(Of MyType)
    Get
        Return _list
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of MyType))
        _list= value
        _totalField1 = _list.Sum(Function(x) x.Field1)
    End Set
End Property
```

What I'm trying to do is every time a MyType object is added to the list keep a running total of Field1, but adding to the list doesn't use the setter. How can I know when the list has been added or changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use BindingList class, rather than List
BindingList  has events fired when any item is changed/added/deleted.

see for example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/BindingListExamples.aspx

Comment: yeah or basically any kind of observable collection will do in my opinion.